# How to use alias in command_string?

Tags: bash, bashrc

Normally I have a .bashrc file where ll alias is set as

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

When I invoke `ll` manually, it works just fine. However, sometimes I may need to run command from a string. So I would like to run:

```
COMMAND="ll"
bash --login -c "$COMMAND"
```

Unfortunately this complains that ll command is not found and fails. If I check alises it is indeed defined in this scope, I check like this:

```
COMMAND="alias"
bash --login -c "$COMMAND"
```

the above mentioned prints all my aliases properly.

Is there any way to use aliased commands in bash's -c command_string parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to note here, first about running with the `--login` option:

```
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter‐
active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com‐
mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading
that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
exists and is readable.
```

So, this command is not reading your `.bashrc`.  Secondly, aliases only work in interactive shells, so even if this alias were being sourced it would not work in your command.  Functions, however, do work in non-interactive shells. So, you should convert your aliases to functions and source them in one of the things mentioned above, such as `~/.bash_profile`.

Alternatively, you can export functions defined in the current environment to the one inherited by `bash -c`.  I have this function:

```
adrian@adrian:~$ type fn
fn is a function
fn () 
{ 
    find . -name "$1"
}
```

Which I can call in a subshell like this:

```
adrian@adrian:~$ export -f fn
adrian@adrian:~$ bash -c "fn foo*"
./foo.bar
```

Comment: While it is correct that by default, are not expanded in non-interactive shells, this can be configured (using `shopt expand_aliases`).

Answer (score 2):

`.bashrc` is only read under certain conditions, so make that happen:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
echo being read
alias foo='echo bar'
$ bash -c foo
bash: foo: command not found
$ bash -i -c foo
being read
bar
$
```

A quick skim through `bash(1)` for `interactive` then might turn up

```
   Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description  of
   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
```

which may give several other ways to enable this besides throwing `-i` into the argument list.

(That being said, I absolutely do not use aliases in non-interactive shells such as `bash -c`)